# Matching two raster world maps which start from different longitude using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, overlay

I'm trying to use the raster calculator for two different maps.
But the thing is they start from different longitude like this,
And I don't know how to fix the "not overlayed" area problem.
Could you give me a hint about this problem?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Try getting the data to overlap. Have a look at my answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/438246/netcdf-file-and-shapefile-in-wildly-different-locations-and-of-disproportionate/438251#438251